# Modifying/Changing time in Bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way to change the current time to a another time in bash? For example, if I were to pass in current time (assume 4:00pm) as an argument to a file, is there a way I can pass 3pm to the file?

Thanks.

Comment: `man date`.....

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
received_time="3:00pm"
date +%I:%M%p -d "$received_time - 1 hour"
```

## Explanation

From `date --help`:

```
Usage: date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
-d, --date=STRING          display time described by STRING, not 'now'
FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted sequences are:
    %I   hour (01..12)
    %M   minute (00..59)
    %p   locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known
```